Main size file database SQLite doesn't update, but -wal file does
I'm getting a problem by exporting a SQLite Database.
I'm reading the main file database (database.db) but always when I export it, the data is equal to the before file.
Strangly, the database-wal file is updating its file size always I add a new row in the local database. So, I don't know what I should to do, to export the last rows added.
This is my export code:
protected Boolean exportarBD(Context context, Activity activity) throws IOException {
        Boolean exported = false;

        if (!Permisos.validarWriteExternalStorage(context, activity)){
            return exported;
        }

        File backupDir = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "mydatabase/backup");
        if (!backupDir.exists()) {
            backupDir.mkdirs(); // Crea los directorios si no existen
        }

        // Define el nombre del archivo exportado
        File exportFile = new File(backupDir, "DB_exported" + (new Date()).toString() + ".db");

        File dbFile = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("database.db").getAbsolutePath());
        if (dbFile.exists()) {
            // Usa un flujo para copiar la base de datos al nuevo archivo
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(exportFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();


            exported = true;
        } else {
            exported = false;
        }

        return exported;
    }

I'm download the main file database, but this file doesn't have the last rows added

This question is similar to: Is there a way to flush changes in SQLite database file in android?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you don't want to loose the benefits of SQLite's Write Ahead Logging instead of disabling it all you need to do is make sure a checkpoint is performed to move the data from the wal file to the main database file.
The easiest way to perform this is to close all connections to the database with something like db.close();
Once there is no active connections to the database the checkpoint will be performed and the main database file will be updated with the last rows ready for export.
Sorry I cannot be more specific but you don't show enough code to suggest where the database close should be done.

Ok, I will review all my database queries to find a connection close missed

That works bro. Thanks.
I had to carry out the checkpoint runtime (with pragma wal_checkpoint(full); ) then to close the conexcion with db.close() and it works.

If making sure a checkpoint is performed works please mark the question as answered. Thanks

How do I do it? I've marked like accepted this answer but the question wasn't marked like "solved"
